# Print a half pyramid of numbers in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose, you are given a positive integer. Now, print a numerical triangle of height like the below one. More than 2 lines will result in a 0 score.

> 1
>
> 22
>
> 333
>
> 4444
>
> 55555

My code:

```
for i in range(1,int(input())): #More than 2 lines will result in 0 score. Do not leave a blank line also
    for j in range(i):
        print((j+1), end="")
    print("\n")
```

I'm able to do it in two print statements, but not in one.  How would I condense it to one?

Comment: Your code outputs a different pyramid. `1,. 12,. 123,. 1234,. 12345`.

Comment: What do you mean by "0 score"? Are you giving us a score if we answer your question? Is this a quiz?

Comment: `for i in range(1, int(input())): print(('%d' % i ) * i)`

Answer (score 4):

You can use a list comprehension with a single `print` call:

```
print('\n'.join(str(i)*i for i in range(1, 6)))
```

Output:

```
1
22
333
4444
55555
```

Answer (score 0):

There's lots of ways you could do this, for example, using a list comprehension:

```
for i in range(1,int(input())):
    print([i for j in range(i)])
```

And then maybe you want to change the output into strings instead of lists, in which case you can do:

```
for i in range(1,int(input())):
    print("".join([str(i) for j in range(i)]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
for i in range(1, int(input()) + 1):
    print(''.join(str(i) for j in range(i)))
```

**Output**

```
1
22
333
4444
55555
```

**Note:** The above output was for `input = 5`

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(1,int(input())):
    print((10**i)//9*i)
```

By using this code you can print the pattern by without using string function and the code comes within two lines.